# jquery tabs with extra padding on create/remove new tabs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, spacing

I have an issue with Jquery Tabs and to be more precise with padding between each tabs that, on my page, I create and delete several times.

Every time that I create and delete a tab, and extra space is left on tabs area:

[image: example]

Why the distance between [ Main Tab ] and [ Tab 1 ] is not the same between [ Tab 1 ] and [ Tab 9 ] considering that in the middle 8 new tabs has been created and removed?

**HTML:**

```
<div id='demo'>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#main">Main Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ref">Tab 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='main'>Main</div>
<div id='ref'>Reference tab</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$( '#demo' ).tabs();
var tabs = $( "#demo" ).tabs();
var ul = tabs.find("ul");
//-- Create 10 tabs
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $( "<li><a href='#tab" + i + "'>Tab " + i + " </a></li>" ).appendTo(ul);
    $( "<div id='tab" + i + "' style=''>This is the tab " + i + "</div>" ).appendTo(tabs);
}
tabs.tabs('refresh');

//-- Delete 9 tabs
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    $( "#demo ul a[href^=#tab" + i + "]" ).remove();
    $( "#demo div[id^=tab" + i + "]" ).remove();
}
tabs.tabs('refresh');
```

This is the JsFiddle to reproduce it

http://jsfiddle.net/wh3ct1cn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're removing just the anchors, and not the entire list items. Here's a fix:

```
$( "#demo ul a[href^=#tab5]" ).parent('li').remove();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wh3ct1cn/2/)

---

Rather than deleting them from the DOM, why not use the `remove()` function?

```
//-- Delete tabs 5, 6, and 7
for (i = 7; i > 4; i--) {
    $("#demo").tabs('remove', i);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wh3ct1cn/1/)

I'm working in reverse order because the indexes change after each operation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the li element, not the a element.

> $( "#demo ul a[href^=#tab" + i + "]" ).parent().remove();

Comment: Hah, thanks @isherwood!  I decided to start being a good citizen by upvoting questions/answers that help me out, but I don't have enough points to do that.  So I figured I'd try to answer a few of the low hanging fruit to get to +15... but man, people answer these questions *fast* ;-)